# Error al intentar conectarme a mi base de datos de PostgreSQL a través de Django y a través de imagen de Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

Tengo un problema respecto a conectarme a mi base de datos PostgreSQL a través de Django.
No entiendo cual es el error siendo que he probado de muchas maneras y no identifico cual es mi problema para poder realizar el makemigrations y el migrate.

A continuación, la parte principal de mi código de settings.py relacionado con la conexión a la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también lo que me devuelve el comando de $ docker compose ps:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también lo que tengo en mi docker-compose.yalm:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]